# Объявление строки во время компиляции

Tags: c++, строки, c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr auto get_str() {
    return std::string{"Hello, world!"};
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto str = get_str();
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Почему код не компилируется?

```
error: 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>{std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::_Alloc_hider{((char*)(& str.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<anonymous>.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<unnamed union>::_M_local_buf))}, 13, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<unnamed union>{char [16]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', 0}}}' is not a constant expression
```

Если не объявлять переменную, то всё ок:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr auto get_str() {
    return std::string{"Hello, world!"};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_str() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Конструктор std::string не является `constexpr` и не может быть вызван во время компиляции. Во втором случае функция не вызывается в контексте `constexpr`.

Comment: @user7860670 https://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons

Comment: Компилятор же написал, что `is not a constant expression`. Для `constexpr` следует использовать компилятор с поддержкой C++20.

Comment: @user7860670 я использую компилятор с поддержкой C++20

Comment: Если бы это было так, то компилятор не ругался. Убедитесь, что действительно используется с++20.

Comment: @user7860670 https://godbolt.org/z/x8oqz6xcY

Comment: Тогда тут другая проблема: `::std::string` не является не может использоваться в качестве возвращаемого значению `constexpr` функции в `constexpr` контексте, так как динамически выделяемая память должна освобождаться в `constexpr` функции, в которой она была выделена.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working

Comment: Если хотите получить константное выражение, то  благоразумно будет возвращать std::string_view

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказывает ошибка компилятора, чтобы объявить переменную `str` со спецификатором `constexpr`, надо инициализировать её с помощью *constant expression*.

[[dcl.constexpr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.constexpr#10):

> ... In any constexpr variable declaration, the full-expression of the
> initialization shall be a constant expression. ...

Однако выражение `get_str()` не является *core constant expression* (ниже рассмотрим подробно). Т.к. выражение не является *core constant expression*, то оно не является и *constant expression*.

[[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#11):

> **A constant expression is either** a glvalue **core constant expression**
> that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
> expression (as defined below), **or** a prvalue **core constant expression**
> whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - ...

---

Чтобы показать, что `get_str()` не является *core constant expression*, для начала заметим, что в данном случае оно эквивалентно выражению `std::string{"Hello, world!"}`.

[[expr.call]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.call#9):

> **The result of a function call is the result of the** possibly-converted **operand of the return statement that transferred
> control out of the called function (if any)**, <strike>except in a virtual
> function call if the return type of the final overrider is different
> from the return type of the statically chosen function, the value
> returned from the final overrider is converted to the return type of
> the statically chosen function</strike>.

Это выражение эквивалентно `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>{"Hello, world!"}`.

[[string.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/string.syn):

```
...
namespace std {
  template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>, class Allocator = allocator<charT>> 
  class basic_string;
  ...
  using string    = basic_string<char>;
  ...
}
```

Оно вызывает `std::allocator_­traits<std​::​allocator<U>​>​::​rebind_­traits<char>​::​​construct` для некоторого типа `U`, определённого ниже (по крайней мере, [as if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)).

[[string.cons]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/string.cons):

```
...
constexpr basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
...
```

[[string.require]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/string.require#3):

> ... Every object of type `basic_­string<charT, traits, Allocator>`
> uses an object of type `Allocator` to allocate and free storage for
> the contained `charT` objects as needed. The `Allocator` object used
> is obtained as described in
> [[container.requirements.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/container.requirements.general).
> ...

[[container.requirements.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/container.requirements.general#3):

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an
> `allocator_­type`, objects stored in these components shall be
> constructed using the function
> `allocator_­traits<allocator_­type>​::​rebind_­traits<U>​::​​construct`
> and destroyed using the function
> `allocator_­traits<allocator_­type>​::​rebind_­traits<U>​::​​destroy`,
> where `U` is either `allocator_­type​::​value_­type` or an internal
> type used by the container.

Это эквивалентно `std​::​allocator<U>​::construct`.

[[allocator.traits]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/allocator.traits#general-1):

```
...
namespace std {
  ...
  template<class T> using rebind_alloc = *see below*;
  template<class T> using rebind_traits = allocator_traits<rebind_alloc<T>>;
  ...
}
```

[[allocator.traits.types]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/allocator.traits.types#11):

> `template<class T> using rebind_alloc` = *see below*;
>
> *Alias template*: `Alloc​::​rebind<T>​::​other` if the *qualified-id* `Alloc​::​rebind<T>​::​other` is valid and denotes a type
> ([[temp.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.deduct));
> otherwise, **`Alloc<T, Args>` if `Alloc` is a class template
> instantiation of the form `Alloc<U, Args>`, where `Args` is zero** or
> more type arguments; otherwise, the instantiation of `rebind_­alloc`
> is ill-formed.

Таким образом, `get_str()` не является *core constant expression*, т.к. срабатывает следующий пункт стандарта (память не освобождается во время *constant evaluation*, т.к. она используется для инициализации `str`, которая продолжает свой *lifetime* до конца блока):

[[expr.const]/5.19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#5.19):

> An expression E is a core constant expression **unless the evaluation** of
> E, following the rules of the abstract machine, **would evaluate** one of the following :
>
> - ...
> - **a call to an instance of `std​::​allocator<T>​::​allocate`** ([[allocator.members]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/allocator.members)), <strike>unless the allocated storage is deallocated within the evaluation of E</strike>;
> - ...

---

Возможна ли ситуация, когда память освобождается до конца константного выражения?<sup>†</sup> — Да, например, в [следующем коде](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:37,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:37,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:37,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:37,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+auto+get_str()+%7B%0A++++return+std::string%7B%22Hello,+world!!%22%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::size(get_str()))%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.99999999999999,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%27),(compilerId:g122,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_32_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.99999999999999,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
#include <string>

constexpr auto get_str() {
    return std::string{"Hello, world!"};
}

static_assert(std::size(get_str()));
```

Значит, сама по себе функция *well-formed*.

[[dcl.constexpr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.constexpr#6):

> **For a constexpr function** or constexpr constructor **that is neither
> defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an
> invocation of the function** or constructor **could be an evaluated
> subexpression of a *core constant expression***, or, for a constructor,
> an evaluated subexpression of the initialization full-expression of
> some constant-initialized object
> ([[basic.start.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.start.static)),
> **the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**. ...

Поэтому второй пример из вопроса валиден — там `constexpr` функция используется не в константном выражении.

[[dcl.constexpr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.constexpr#8):

> An invocation of a constexpr function in a given context produces the
> same result as an invocation of an equivalent non-constexpr function
> in the same context in all respects except that
>
> - an invocation of a constexpr function can appear in a constant expression
>   ([[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const))
>   and
> - copy elision is not performed in a constant expression ([[class.copy.elision]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.copy.elision)).
>
> ...

<sup><sup>†</sup> Этот вопрос нам интересен до С++23, начиная с которого можно объявлять `constexpr` функции даже если они никогда не смогут использоваться в константных выражениях. См. [P2448](https://wg21.link/p2448).</sup>

---

Что делать, если мы таки хотим иметь `constexpr` переменную для строки? В таком случае можно [использовать *non-owning* `std::string_view`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcYl2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOa1D3aG9pf3xAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuTgoExJisB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHJ8ShwJfXd7ehBLssTFCEFm%2B3iVluu0huzQDBOmFUSWIuyYXiIu1ezwAIuiCOgQCBXu8APoANzwmAA7iYweYzAAJTC0WioUi7CkkWjoMBgWnUzEHcE3KE4vEoRZ/A5uSU4pGS6VgNYAVjcDAVAq%2BfI481onEVvD8HC0pFQnCllms6MWyyeGx4pAImi18wA1iBFRp9JxJPrHcbOLwFCAPQ7DVrSHBYDBECB4VVUSRyJR6sAFMpDIyhAhUBSDXa0CwknQmI4BGmwrRM9mDUb84X6HFtoZgFx3R7a3RYgB5VGVnOcO2x5A3Ygp/2BVRVWr4A28fiCERidhSGSCRQqdSh0i6Lj6JsoazWfR4KKByDzVBJEuwzgAWhO6AOmNM5ssZg0uzvuNox8f36iz6sSwAytFY9HvUIywzLM%2B24XhTkwVY7QpYgmCSfswx1Dg9VIateBNDhsAnZB4yRVQAA4ADYbwoyRoQMIxdhbAA6DQWN2CAzUAmxdlwQgSH2Mx1i4WY4MdWYXRAdZ1iYqTZLk%2BSKM9DhvVIFhJLMJiuHiCjtIo9YNHWABOMizC4MicN9fCAyDe0xPDKMICQQcSMTCBk1TdMK2g3NeHbAwr0gryq19Pz%2BmbMwAlC4hu2Ebz0PHKph1HDheEHKdQjHOdhFEcRlyytc1F9XQAno4wD0sI8T3gc9LwyQMOE/B91ifcqLDfYCllAndwIYQLex8%2B0zkQ3hkNQ9DtV1H1N3wwi4yIUjKOo2jgGQZBGI0sx2M4w8ePweaBKEkTbNDcTSAQc4sDiYElJUtT1g0yQyI0eJJAowz1jIsiuA0QSLOmsdA2DOyI2jZz5tc9y%2Bri2DSD84sMih4LNyikASWQJIklJLhDKJe6iXIxSopi/r4sHJL6tSoj0pnFdssXCRpHypRCs3XR1l3Ix9xfGw/1Pa6LyveqAHp7y5rj2oWTql0GadEZgu14OG0hRrQ2CJqwqajRmoiSN2An/gUNHdhJbGZM2jjWtZXj9ttI6Qy0U7zqYS7KHV27JMVGTJDMR6dMVeI320v6tYBmz7adUhXXdJT1k1vCx3D07MLMOO/RS46HfmElYjSZxJCAA%3D%3D) (не нужны выделения памяти):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    constexpr auto str = std::string_view{"Hello, world!"};
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

А если нужны какие-то сложные манипуляции над строкой (раз в вопросе использована отдельная функция для этого)? Тогда можно использовать [следующую технику](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwDspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAKwAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/kEZWY4CYRHRLHEJKbaY9qUMQgRMxAR5Pn6BdQ05za0E5VGx8UmpCi1tHQXdEwNDldVjAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuYsAkhAgsZ9gmGgCCewdHmKfnrcRMAJ73jxeZn2DEOXhOZzcaFBmDSBAUAOer1B70%2BUIm6CwVERQJBYIh50I8SYRGIOOR%2BI%2BkImxHCwHJwLe4Kp5xpdIA%2BgA3PCYADu5OeBEwLDSBiFaIIvzSjFYH05Yi8mHZkulOJpXgcx1QnPiWQAXph0Ozvn9TgErM9jlbjhiQCATf9zvLvEqVZhSDaCOg7frXSZzVw0ZDjlwNP6ACL3Y7oElMM4WY4AekTxwMxGAH0Y62ACBteANx2hc0EgOtxzdzDY0cwhzdEBjLWWPvzrqlH198cBpetRaFqjSxGOTC8RGOcWA4Qgy0LAgmxwYqEwqi2cLNFqeZbLxEwBA2DE93pA48nDaYy07lutEa7l6tvaXA6HI9Qx1cU5nDDnC6XK4Ia%2B7m7HF4WRGFqVBUEoBDKm2nzhuWbaVu2Xp2kSPyksqPyEAi5xYLWbYQLaR6YBODD1rGyznrs2B2vg4HxIwWzQaquzroBVrbruxD7oRESqAQBHIURJFkY2HpzI4yDsqIEyQqg4GQUxmD3ARLYUReG5XgEkZIlp6mAkKIpiiybiEdCOptHgMT0MqqDUoJbJGFyPL8lRnq0o5bo4ve/aDsOo5EOy2q6i2RoOhAvZuRynlmMkbnTv6rHWn5L4OrBWrmb6oXED8jpuBWsqRR5bZ2s6iqKQC5oAHS%2BmlhG%2BgJxDnrpLE3hpVqmagaS/AJh7IMepE0qsB52lsDDoA1Q2Ef1EAOpVp5qS1SK3scHF7kO2V/HpulLU8BmiiSxmEeEnKoKIVkfMdp1MOd5VUYC3mPsl5aoOytI5lBmXGht3WXWd1luscv3XfQ8XmgBH4TA%2BvnPulwUGllOVpQFQXEJ9YVA%2BdU6Ueu4PAXSxyla20pIwhBWEbhfzKpCuG0HWKNo99c3kfcJUKkTSmLW1w32t9kKE4pHr0yFX05dVLZRg6enLR1XU9SN01C/DIt/JNgmjeNiuGsrvyq4e00OgtOPLatXHrTlW3aS8grCvt4qQk9p44uEtDhB8D3Q0Q5ixSwTAANZKuJeDIGljuc/pNtGWiR0MCdf0XTHV03Z5d3PO7T7%2BS9DnAE5fIQBj/0wfnmCg4ld6zn%2ByVe56JJB%2Byp5pT7/vsoHpjnAFb0IB9wvownceUQ8YfLXjoH8wDZxwflVbkzWlMENTNa0/hLd18zVGsy6t2lytO5rVNTBZJJWc5y5bij22ymmdNy/zWJatvtf5HY1221W08adPRmH0EMQ74JeDT1oEMkuQK0o0I5AUGlEwiQrCJHDO%2BNOf9lpliejSWq9lv50j/mYMwAAJeotBUAel5CQWg6AwBgHMGYa8nM2KnCQdaGklVtz7S2BADQHouAekoQgShT96FWnBluHepsaTqTLNQo2XMTb7gCkfbkudAGimAZ1YkjQFB8JeC/QE4Q/w%2B0nCXcG78YaoPHscT%2Bzdv5TjEdaaRbkxYGisWHLSHBVi0E4IkXgfgOBaFIKgTgbhrDWBtOsTYVJgQ8FIAQTQLjVi%2BxAMkAIlUAAckhgQAE5dgpGSMkSQaSAhmH0JwSQnjom%2BM4LwBQIB2FRO8S40gcBYAwEQCAJcNZnxkAoDNdMChlCGHqEIBAqBeReIiYougNcBC9IiLQAZQyRm8DGfQBIhxDDAC4IkDQ7DFnxAAPIjlmcMzgETWnICeN08pwRVA1maPgLxvB%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQtTSC6E4QYIwKBAmWH0JZSpkBVidTUZwAAtBicephLDWDMBoY4sKvQuxiOPDFCKrCWAqSErYegMThCmf0wZhzuC8G/pgbYETeQ/DSEcupbiOAeNIF4nxfiODYCucgdpxxVBJOSNCnJhZ/nABDIkSqGhpXHAgAExFwLji4EICQU44TlhUuiRRUgcTdi7Eqvqo1xqTWpBZcU0gLAQD6sqmkjQ2CkkaC4AEXYARkgbOkBy3gXKKlVMidq%2BpTSIBIBOe08glBWjAB6X0mZ5L5mkEWRMhgpLY1zKZQm1AIo6CjDWdgjNWall7OEHG9NJyzlRouScm54QLkPOEKIcQry60fLUKU3QBTxWAsVTYDFYKpy%2BLhOAmFcLdjhhxUinxCgCUvNsF6ElMaDnxupbS3g9KmCMspa49xJTvlcp5W00kAqhUiskGY5AwcuBmEqmYOVCrcU2GVfgQ9ewuCav9bUnVCBMBMCwAkft5reBWptVwNJIGzBJMSAEDQAQNn2vZaUn1tg/U1K0KsBpzTQ2knDV0qNKbF3psTY0PDJbKX5rSNmhInJkBpDSFyED7JdhmHZIK1I2ziBFvw6Rst5yOC8CrXOu5bz63PIkNIZtShW3fN0LsfQqyu33pBTEPtELB2zk4ImW047LDIvxRsQlnDiXJoXSRiJy701ro3TwLdrKd2cs4Puvlh6WPHBYAoKjBMQOGpvfKoFD6VXPo1Vqj9qwv0/tGP%2BopgHrVXrtZB0DZhEiJEkCktJnqEMXMqdU7VsSJAxYS8lj1l7wPAkSIUjguxbPeouShup6Hg0oEzeRpZ2G2MgFzQUmgtNdSUBiKUmI4RWi/AI5mtgggdkMFoEN75WAfZGHENNvA24HB4B1JU75mGV3kEEPUUpGKfjEF%2BB4LApSMFWo/XwAwUaABqzkdnSnjXWp5jaxOyBbV8nxvzZMAq0z20F8AVNQo4Gi9A8LfPItRTsswFT6g1kaC4Ma0w/CcNCK7RYoxOHFGyAIRHehMeNAWCMBIBmYfLYEP0KYnhOhEpJ40cngxUeE6JZMdolOCgGeZwTqo6PVhTr0zOszm6ytsq9WUjgLGT1novVe7zd7rAen82ql9HoPAFviOq3Yr6guoZC9%2B39lAcueeBGYS9XBdhpON9gjQkgzWRfg7ujLyHstlah5aiQmy7d2d4%2B%2B7XpAMo5BAJIIAA%3D) (основано на идее из [C++ Weekly - Ep 313](https://youtu.be/ABg4_EV5L3w)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <typename value_type>
struct oversized_array {
    std::array<value_type, std::size_t{1 << 10}> data; // large enough size constant
    typename decltype(data)::size_type size;

    constexpr auto begin() const noexcept {
        return std::begin(data);
    }

    constexpr auto end() const noexcept {
        using offset_type = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(data))>::difference_type;
        return std::next(std::begin(data), static_cast<offset_type>(size));
    }
};

template <std::convertible_to<std::string_view> string_type>
constexpr auto to_oversized_array(const string_type& str) {
    auto array = oversized_array<typename string_type::value_type>{.size = std::size(str)};

    std::copy(std::cbegin(str), std::cend(str), std::begin(array.data));

    return array;
}

template <std::invocable invocable_type>
constexpr auto to_right_sized_array(invocable_type invocable) {
    constexpr auto oversized_array = to_oversized_array(invocable());

    using value_type = typename std::decay_t<decltype(oversized_array.data)>::value_type;
    std::array<value_type, oversized_array.size> array;

    std::copy(std::cbegin(oversized_array), std::cend(oversized_array), std::begin(array));

    return array;
}

template <auto data>
inline constexpr auto& make_static = data;

template <std::invocable invocable_type>
constexpr auto to_string_view(invocable_type invocable) {
    const auto& static_data = make_static<to_right_sized_array(invocable)>;

    using value_type = typename std::decay_t<decltype(static_data)>::value_type;
    return std::basic_string_view<value_type>(std::cbegin(static_data), std::cend(static_data));
}

constexpr auto get_str() {
    auto complex_operations = []() constexpr {
        auto str = std::string{"Hello, world!"};
        
        str.replace(0, 1, "h");
        
        return str;
    };

    return to_string_view(complex_operations);
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto str = get_str();
    return str.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Память, выделенная в куче во время компиляции, должна быть освобождена во время компиляции (ее нельзя пронести в рантайм), иначе выделение памяти не считается константным выражением.

Поскольку `main()` выполняется в рантайме, переменная `str` тоже должна существовать в рантайме, т. е. память должна быть освобождена не во время компиляции, а позднее, в рантайме.

Поэтому, например, вот так можно:

```
constexpr std::size_t foo()
{
    return std::string("Hello, world!").size();
}

constexpr std::size_t x = foo();
```

Тут строка сразу уничтожается, и не доживает до рантайма.

Чтобы починить код в вопросе, символы должны быть не в куче, а в `std::array` или его аналоге.

---

Интересно, почему тут вообще память выделяется в куче, если строка достаточно короткая для SSO. Видимо оно отключается в `constexpr` выражениях, потому что хитрые трюки с `union`-ами/`reinterpret_cast`-ами не работают во время компиляции...