# Можно ли как-то узнать, пустая ли строка при помощи шаблонов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Решил поиграться со SFINAE и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу узнать длину строки при помощи шаблонов, по крайней мере компилятор ругается. Можете ли подсказать, в чем моя ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
template<std::string& str, bool init = str.empty()>
struct is_empty : std::false_type
{};

template<std::string& str>
struct is_empty<str, true> : std::true_type
{};

template<std::string& str>
using is_empty_t = typename is_empty<str>::type;
}

int main()
{
   std::string str;
   std::cout << detail::is_empty_t<str>::type << std::endl;
}
```

Может я написал какой-то ужас. Можете подсказать, что конкретно не так?

Comment: Пардон, описался, узнать, пустая ли строка

Comment: Нельзя. Параметр шаблона должен быть константой времени компиляции.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1390056/312941

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033110/6944845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, что использование SFINAE в данном случае избыточно. Достаточно наследоваться от `bool_constant`, которое параметризуется значением `str.empty()`:

```
template<String str>
struct IsEmpty : std::bool_constant<str.empty()> {}
```

Но это, скорее, замечание, нежели ответ на Ваш вопрос.

---

В моем примере `String` это что-то вроде:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct String
{
    constexpr explicit String(const char(&str)[N])
        : value()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) value[i] = str[i];
    }

    char value[N];
};
```